# change content of UIPickerView when hour changes?

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker, uipickerview

Solution: I could just trigger a NSTimer when the hour will change, by creating it at the beginning in viewDidLoad.

Previous message:
I would like to change the content in the list in a UIPickerView, so that the first option is always the current hour +1. If the user starts the app at 15:59, the first item will be 16:00. But if it is 16:01, the first item should be 17:00.
How could I reload the data so that anytime the user look at the picker, the first item is always the currentHour+1? 
I reinitialize the `array` in `loadData()`, and if I add it in viewforRow, the pickerView is empty.

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return array.count
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
        return array[row]
    }

    func loadData(){
        var formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "HH"
        let date = NSDate()
        let str = formatter.stringFromDate(date)
        let hourNow = str.toInt()!
        if ( hourNow+1 < 22 ){
            array = [String]()
            for (var i = hourNow+1; i<22; i++) { //if 15:00:
                let num : Int = i //starts at 16:00
                array.append(num.toString())
            }
        }
    }

    //view for row
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView!) -> UIView {
        var mView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0, 50,20))
        let label = UILabel(frame:CGRectMake(0,0, 50,20))
        label.text = array[row]
        mView.addSubview(label)
        return mView
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the current hour of the day and just add one:

```
func currentHourPlusOne()->Int{
    var now = NSDate()

    var calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    var components = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitHour, fromDate: now)

    return components.hour + 1
}
```

Or, the short version(Thanks to [Leonardo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2303865/leonardo-savio-dabus))

```
func currentHourPlusOne()->Int{
    return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().component(.CalendarUnitHour, fromDate: NSDate()) + 1
}
```

As you see, I take the current date and load it into a `NSCalendar` where i take just the hour. The hour gets always the current hour. For example if it's 10:30, the hour is 10. So you just need to add one hour and you've got what you wanted.

And to reload your `UIPickerView` just call `reloadAllComponents` on your picker after you've updated your array as last line in your `loadData` method:

```
func loadData(){
    var formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "HH"
    let date = NSDate()
    let str = formatter.stringFromDate(date)
    let hourNow = str.toInt()!
    if ( hourNow+1 < 22 ){
        array = [String]()
        for (var i = hourNow+1; i<22; i++) { //if 15:00:
            let num : Int = i //starts at 16:00
            array.append(num.toString())
        }
    }
    picker.reloadAllComponents()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this method. About the reload, yes, but where can I put this reload method?

Comment: Put it in somewhere, after you've updated your array. Currently in your loadData.

Comment: You should change .HourCalendarUnit to the new format .CalendarUnitHour

Comment: return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().component(.CalendarUnitHour, fromDate: NSDate()) + 1

Comment: OK thanks for the answer, I actually can just trigger the method with a simple NSTimer that works only once. I will keep the advice for the method with NSCalendar, thanks for the answer